# When manually setting up hard drives in the installer, how can I set custom mount points?

Tags: 11.04, installation, mount, automount, ubiquity

With previous versions of Ubuntu, you could specify mount points for various hard drives and partitions during the installation process.  This was useful, because I have a backup hard drive that I set to mount at /media/backup.  When installing Ubuntu 11.04, I can see the box that I used to type this info into, but it doesn't allow keyboard input and I can only choose the pre-defined mount points (e.g. "/" and "/home").

[image: Cant type in the Mount point box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was not intentional** -- it's actually [a bug in the installer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/769043) that was noticed too late to be fixed in time for Ubuntu 11.04.

**There is a workaround** -- you can type the mount point you want ("/media/backup") in a text document, then copy and paste the text into the box in the installer.

**Update** -- This has now been fixed.  I doubt they'll re-release the Ubuntu 11.04 disk image, but at least we shouldn't have to worry about this problem in 11.10.